# Adding Data to a table with Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I want to add data to my App table in Visual Studio. When I run the program, I fill the information into the text boxes, and when I click the add button, I receive this message from this code:

> "Cmd.ExecuteNONQuerry" : An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

When I run "Build Solution" I receive this:

> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Can somebody please help me.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class APP

    Dim Con As New SqlConnection

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonAdd.Click
        Con.Open()

        Dim Cmd As New SqlCommand(("INSERT INTO App VALUES('" & _
                                   ID.Text & "','" & _
                                   Dat.Text & "','" & _
                                   Inst.Text & "', '" & _
                                   Credent.Text & "', '" & _
                                   AppOwner.Text & "', '" & _
                                   Status.Text & "', '" & _
                                   SerialNr.Text & "', '" & _
                                   MAC.Text & "', '" & _
                                   DellNr.Text & "', '" & _
                                   Model.Text & "', '" & _
                                   Description.Text & _
                                   "', '" & Service.Text & _
                                   "', '" & Indkøbt.Text & "',)"), Con)

        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Con.Close()

        MsgBox("Success....", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "SUCCESS")

        ID.Clear()
        Dat.Clear()
        Inst.Clear()
        Credent.Clear()
        AppOwner.Clear()
        Status.Clear()
        SerialNr.Clear()
        MAC.Clear()
        DellNr.Clear()
        Model.Clear()
        Description.Clear()
        Service.Clear()
        Indkøbt.Clear()

        ID.Focus()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=BYG-A101-MOELKA;Initial Catalog=App;Integrated Security=True"

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the first glance:

```
"', '" & Indkøbt.Text & "',)"), Con)
```

is wrong, it should be

```
"', '" & Indkøbt.Text & "')"), Con)
```

But there is another big Problem: you are not using sqlparameters, so your code will crash if someone enters a "'".

When using an insert like you do, it´s also ... more readable if you also specify the field list to see, if you inserting values in the correct databasefield. But much better change to sqlparameters.

**Addition - SQL Parameters (with an update Statement, but the principle should be clear):**

```
sqlStmt = "UPDATE table SET fieldname = @fieldparameter WHERE ..."
Using sqlComm As New SqlCommand(sqlStmt, sqlConn)
   sqlComm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@fieldparameter", yourvalue))
   sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Comment: I'm really new at this. Which parameter and where should i add it.

Comment: I´ll post an example in a few minutes - and just did it

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked now though i get this message each time i run my code "There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build"

I must confess, i do not know what your code mean and how to use parameters...But at least its filling data in

Comment: if you get compile rrors, there is a chance that you didn´t declare all variables.